# How to access locked notes with forgotten password?

Tags: ios, password, notes.app

I've forgotten my Notes.app password and the hint I left myself is no help. I have the ability to reset the password in Settings, but all my old notes that used the old password would remain locked. Is there any way that I can access these locked notes? I'm thinking of the sort of program that tries different different combinations of characters until it figures out the password like you would see in a hacking movie if that's real.

Comment: Have a look at this: [How to Reset Forgotten Apple Notes Password on iPhone, iPad, and Mac](https://bit.ly/3iAiQul)  See if that helps you. I'm not a Notes user (I use OneNote) so I don't have good first hand experience with how Notes works.  The tool that you saw in the movies actually exists - it's called a brute force password tool, but it's much, much more complex than what the movies portray.

Comment: Keeping a secure record of your passwords is a lesson for the future.

Answer (score 1):

Hollywood does not have a great track record in accurately portraying technology.

The whole point of passwords and encryption is to make it as difficult as possible (if not impossible) to get in without the password.

Let's say your password was 8 letters long. Using 26 lower-case letters only, the number of combinations is over 200 billion, so trying each password in turn at 1 second each would take 6,500 years.

Your best bet is to think long and hard about the hint, and what you might have meant.